# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Tomcat Server

Tags: java, rest, web-services, vue.js, jersey

I developed a web service (REST) with using java jersey library on tomcat server and it works well when I send requests via a rest client. And I created a front end for my web service with using Vue.js.

However when I try to send request with my vue.js project, I got this warning: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://{My ip,port ...}/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` (I am using mozilla)

Here is how I allowed CORS headers in my web service:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response loginUser(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    JSONObject data = UserInformationProvider.getUserInformation(request);

    return Response.ok().entity(data.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, auth-user")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "9999999").build();
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?